# Output clause of merge within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying create a stored procedure that contains a merge clause and want save output clause to a table (`logs.ProductTaxProfileLog`).

In my search for information I do not see that the output clause is used within the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ProductTaxProfiles
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE dbo.ProductTaxProfiles AS prd
    USING staging.ProductTaxProfiles AS stg
        ON stg.ProductTaxProfileId = prd.ProductTaxProfileId
    -- UPDATE
    WHEN MATCHED AND (
        prd.ProductTaxProfileDescription <> stg.ProductTaxProfileDescription        
        OR prd.ProductIvaConditionId <> stg.ProductIvaConditionId
        OR prd.ProductIvaConditionDescription <> stg.ProductIvaConditionDescription
        OR prd.ProductIibbConditionId <> stg.ProductIibbConditionId
        OR prd.ProductIibbConditionDescription <> stg.ProductIibbConditionDescription
        OR prd.ProductInternalTaxConditionId <> stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionId
        OR prd.ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription <> stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription
        OR prd.McActive <> stg.McActive
        ) THEN 
            UPDATE 
            SET
                prd.ProductTaxProfileDescription = stg.ProductTaxProfileDescription,
                prd.ProductIvaConditionId = stg.ProductIvaConditionId,
                prd.ProductIvaConditionDescription = stg.ProductIvaConditionDescription,
                prd.ProductIibbConditionId = stg.ProductIibbConditionId,
                prd.ProductIibbConditionDescription = stg.ProductIibbConditionDescription,
                prd.ProductInternalTaxConditionId = stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionId,
                prd.ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription = stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription,
                prd.McActive = 1,
                prd.UpdatedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -- INSERT
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (
            ProductTaxProfileId
            ,ProductTaxProfileDescription
            ,ProductIvaConditionId
            ,ProductIvaConditionDescription
            ,ProductIibbConditionId
            ,ProductIibbConditionDescription
            ,ProductInternalTaxConditionId
            ,ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription
            ,McActive
            ,CreatedDate
            ,UpdatedDate
            ,DeletedDate
        )
        VALUES (
            stg.ProductTaxProfileId
            ,stg.ProductTaxProfileDescription
            ,stg.ProductIvaConditionId
            ,stg.ProductIvaConditionDescription
            ,stg.ProductIibbConditionId
            ,stg.ProductIibbConditionDescription    
            ,stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionId
            ,stg.ProductInternalTaxConditionDescription
            ,1
            ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            ,NULL
        )
    -- DELETE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND (prd.McActive <> 0) THEN
        UPDATE
        SET 
            prd.McActive = 0
            ,prd.DeletedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
    OUTPUT 
        CASE
            WHEN $action = 'UPDATE' AND inserted.McActive = 0 AND deleted.McActive = 1 THEN 'DELETE'
            WHEN $action = 'UPDATE' AND inserted.McActive = 1 AND deleted.McActive = 1 THEN 'UPDATE'
            WHEN $action = 'INSERT' AND inserted.McActive = 1 AND COALESCE(deleted.McActive,0) = 0 THEN 'INSERT'
            WHEN $action = 'UPDATE' AND inserted.McActive = 1 AND COALESCE(deleted.McActive,0) = 0 THEN 'RE-INSERT'
        END AS ActionType,
        inserted.*, 
        deleted.*
    INTO logs.ProductTaxProfileLog;
END
GO
```

But I got this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me? I know that merge clause needs a semicolon at the end, but I really don't know how fix this error.

Comment: have you tried to remove remove the last ; before ProductTaxProfileLog?

Comment: Is there additional code in the procedure you are not including in the question, or additional code in the batch where the procedure is being called? Your merge appears to be syntactically correct.

Comment: Same here! I couldn't reproduce the said behaviour; it works (I have simplified tables for all three tables involved(

Comment: Merge statemente requires the semicolon. When i remove it i got this error:

Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [10713] [S0001]: A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;).

Comment: I'm guessing that there is something else going on here. Do you have any other statements, or are you injecting values into your query? Side note: probably best to define which columns to insert at the line `INTO logs.ProductTaxProfileLog`

Comment: Thank u guys, indeed the syntax was fine, the problem was the ide.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Find the answer.

I was working with dbeaver and for some reason got that error. But when you run it from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) it runs fine, and everything works.

In conclusion the problem was the IDE